# QTableWidget is unstable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I put a QTableWidget on my form, and update it when I get the real-time quote.
Here is the full code of the class:

```
class _GUI_CrossMarketTradingInterface_mainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow_ChinaUSCrossTrading):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(_GUI_CrossMarketTradingInterface_mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.locker = threading.Lock()
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(('localhost', 9090))
        self.server.listen(10)
        self.table_originalQuote.setColumnWidth(6, 150)
        self.table_transformedQuote.setColumnWidth(6, 150)

    def __del__(self):
        self.server.close()

    def setOriginalQuoteTableItem(self, row, col, text):
        itemToSet = QTableWidgetItem(str(text))
        self.locker.acquire()
        self.table_originalQuote.setItem(row, col, itemToSet)
        self.table_originalQuote.item(row, col).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.table_originalQuote.viewport().repaint()
        self.locker.release()

    def setTransformedQuoteTableItem(self, row, col, text):
        itemToSet = QTableWidgetItem(str(text))
        self.locker.acquire()
        self.table_transformedQuote.setItem(row, col, itemToSet)
        self.table_transformedQuote.item(row, col).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.table_transformedQuote.viewport().repaint()
        self.locker.release()
        self.setSpreadQuoteItem()

    def setSpreadQuoteItem(self):
        [spreadBid, spreadAsk] = self.reCalculateSpread()
        itemToSetBid = QTableWidgetItem(str(spreadBid))
        itemToSetAsk = QTableWidgetItem(str(spreadAsk))
        self.locker.acquire()
        self.table_spreadQuote.setItem(0, 1, itemToSetBid)
        self.table_spreadQuote.setItem(0, 2, itemToSetAsk)
        self.table_spreadQuote.item(0, 1).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.table_spreadQuote.item(0, 2).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.table_spreadQuote.viewport().repaint()
        self.locker.release()

    def reCalculateSpread(self):
        try:
            cnBid = float(self.table_transformedQuote.item(0, 1).text())
            cnAsk = float(self.table_transformedQuote.item(0, 2).text())
            usBid = float(self.table_transformedQuote.item(1, 1).text())
            usAsk = float(self.table_transformedQuote.item(1, 2).text())
            spreadBid = round(cnBid - usAsk, 2)
            spreadAsk = round(cnAsk - usBid, 2)
            return [spreadBid, spreadAsk]
        except:
            return ["--", "--"]

    def ib_connect_process(self):
        SetupLogger()
        logging.debug("now is %s", datetime.datetime.now())
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)

        from ibapi import utils
        Order.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        Contract.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        DeltaNeutralContract.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        TagValue.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        TimeCondition.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        ExecutionCondition.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        MarginCondition.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        PriceCondition.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        PercentChangeCondition.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log
        VolumeCondition.__setattr__ = utils.setattr_log

        try:
            app = TestApp()
            app.connect(str(self.txt_IBConnIP.text()), int(self.txt_IBConnPort.text()), clientId=0)
            app.run()
            print("after run!!")
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            app.dumpTestCoverageSituation()
            app.dumpReqAnsErrSituation()

    def ctp_connect_process(self):
        evn_id = int(self.combo_connEvn.currentIndex())
        svr_id = int(self.combo_connServer.currentIndex())
        tmpSvr = (CTP_Server_List.get_ctp_front_server(evn_id, svr_id)).split('|')
        front_trade = tmpSvr[0]
        front_quote = tmpSvr[1]
        broker = CTP_Server_List.get_ctp_broker(evn_id)
        investor = self.txt_ctpAccount.text()
        pwd = self.txt_ctpPasswd.text()
        appid = CTP_Server_List.get_ctp_appid(evn_id)
        auth_code = CTP_Server_List.get_ctp_authcode(evn_id)
        proc = ''

        self.ctp_trade = CTPTrade(front_trade, broker, investor, pwd, appid, auth_code, proc)
        self.ctp_trade.t.ReqConnect(self.ctp_trade.front)
        self.ctp_quote = CTPQuote(front_quote, broker, investor, pwd)
        self.ctp_quote.q.OnConnected = lambda x: self.ctp_quote.q.ReqUserLogin(self.ctp_quote.investor,
                                                                               self.ctp_quote.pwd,
                                                                               self.ctp_quote.broker)
        self.ctp_quote.q.OnUserLogin = lambda o, i: self.ctp_quote.q.ReqSubscribeMarketData(str(self.txt_ChinaSymbol.text()))
        self.ctp_quote.q.ReqConnect(self.ctp_quote.front)

    def quote_to_table_ctp(self):
        conn, address = self.server.accept()
        while _threadRun:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            data = data.split('|')
            self.setOriginalQuoteTableItem(0, 0, int(data[0]))
            self.setTransformedQuoteTableItem(0, 0, int(data[0]))
            self.setOriginalQuoteTableItem(0, 1, float(data[1]))
            self.setTransformedQuoteTableItem(0, 1, float(data[1]))
            self.setOriginalQuoteTableItem(0, 2, float(data[2]))
            self.setTransformedQuoteTableItem(0, 2, float(data[2]))
            self.setOriginalQuoteTableItem(0, 3, int(data[3]))
            self.setTransformedQuoteTableItem(0, 3, int(data[3]))
            self.setOriginalQuoteTableItem(0, 4, float(data[4]))
            self.setTransformedQuoteTableItem(0, 4, float(data[4]))
            self.setOriginalQuoteTableItem(0, 5, int(data[5]))
            self.setTransformedQuoteTableItem(0, 5, int(data[5]))
            cutrrTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            self.setOriginalQuoteTableItem(0, 6, cutrrTime)
            self.setTransformedQuoteTableItem(0, 6, cutrrTime)
        conn.close()

    def ib_run(self):
        self.ib_connect_process()

    def event_cbxConnEvn_CurrentIndexChanged(self):
        print('event_cbxConnEvn_CurrentIndexChanged')
        if int(self.combo_connEvn.currentIndex()) == 0:
            self.combo_connServer.clear()
            self.combo_connServer.addItems(['1. Server - 01',
                                            '2. Server - 02',
                                            '3. Server - 03',
                                            '4. Server - 04',
                                            '5. Server - 05',
                                            '6. Server - 06',
                                            '7. Server - 07',
                                            '8. Server - 08',
                                            '9. Server - 09',
                                            '10. Server - 10',
                                            '11. Server - 11',
                                            '12. Server - 12',
                                            '13. Server - 13',
                                            '14. Server - 14',
                                            '15. Server - 15',
                                            '16. Server - 16'])
        elif int(self.combo_connEvn.currentIndex()) == 1:
            self.combo_connServer.clear()
            self.combo_connServer.addItems(['1. SimServer - 01',
                                            '2. SimServer - 02'])
        else:
            self.combo_connServer.clear()
            self.combo_connServer.addItems(['1. SimServer - 01',
                                            '2. SimServer - 02'])

    def event_btnConnectServer_Clicked(self):
        ctp_quote_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.quote_to_table_ctp)
        ctp_quote_thread.start()
        self.ctp_connect_process()
        ib_run_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.ib_run)
        ib_run_thread.start()

    def event_btnLongSpread1_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnLongSpread1_Clicked')

    def event_btnLongSpread2_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnLongSpread2_Clicked')

    def event_btnLongSpread3_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnLongSpread3_Clicked')

    def event_btnShortSpread1_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnShortSpread1_Clicked')

    def event_btnShortSpread2_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnShortSpread2_Clicked')

    def event_btnShortSpread3_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnShortSpread3_Clicked')

    def event_btnLongChina1_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnLongChina1_Clicked')

    def event_btnLongChina2_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnLongChina2_Clicked')

    def event_btnLongChina3_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnLongChina3_Clicked')

    def event_btnShortChina1_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnShortChina1_Clicked')

    def event_btnShortChina2_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnShortChina2_Clicked')

    def event_btnShortChina3_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnShortChina3_Clicked')

    def event_btnLongUS_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnLongUS_Clicked')

    def event_btnShortUS_Clicked(self):
        print('event_btnShortUS_Clicked')
```

I found that if the table was updated frequently, the program will crash.  It will work fine if I put the table to the background, if I switch it to the front, it crashes.
Is there any way to avoid the crash? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update the GUI directly from another thread since the GUI is not thread-safe, in those cases the simplest option is to use signals.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
class _GUI_CrossMarketTradingInterface_mainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_mainWindow_ChinaUSCrossTrading):
    listChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(_GUI_CrossMarketTradingInterface_mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # ...
        self.listChanged.connect(self.on_listChanged)

    # ...

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(list)
    def on_listChanged(self, l):
        for i, text in enumerate(l):
            for table in (self.table_originalQuote, self.table_transformedQuote):
                itemToSet = QTableWidgetItem(text)
                itemToSet.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
                table.setItem(0, i, itemToSet)

    # ...
    def ib_connect_process(self, ip, port):
        # ...
        try:
            app = TestApp()
            app.connect(ip, port, clientId=0)
            app.run()
            print("after run!!")
        except:
            raise
        finally:
            app.dumpTestCoverageSituation()
            app.dumpReqAnsErrSituation()

    # ...

    def quote_to_table_ctp(self):
        conn, address = self.server.accept()
        while _threadRun:
            data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            data = data.split("|")
            self.listChanged.emit(data[:6])
        conn.close()

    # ...

    def event_btnConnectServer_Clicked(self):
        ctp_quote_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.quote_to_table_ctp)
        ctp_quote_thread.start()
        self.ctp_connect_process()
        ib_run_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self.ib_connect_process,
            args=(self.txt_IBConnIP.text(), int(self.txt_IBConnPort.text()))
        )
        ib_run_thread.start()

   # ...
```

Comment: With a little modification, it can run very well.  Even in high updating circumstances, it is still very stable.  Thank you.